# Is it possible to emit sql from grails/groovy newInstance/saves?

Tags: database, grails, groovy, liquibase, flyway

My team is looking into db migration tools (e.g., Flyway, Liquibase) and so I'm thinking about how to incorporate changes I make to the db contents using my groovy+grails service method. I'm not referring to changes to columns and/or tables (i.e., domain classes), I'm referring to inserts/updates of rows which represent configuration values for the associated webapp.

My service method is written to be used somewhat interactively. That is, when I'm adding or updating rows in various tables (i.e., `newInstance` or `save`), it helps me navigate various db constraints and to make sure all the foreign keys and my own business logic are set correctly. I run it repeatedly (rolling back each time afterwards using `setRollbackOnly()`) until I've found something I'm happy with. The method is written in groovy, and I don't want to rewrite it in sql.

Is there a way to get groovy/grails to emit the sql it would execute instead of executing the sql? That is, give me something I could copy/paste into a Flyway migration or Liquibase changeset?

I looked into [logging](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1604), but I'd have to somehow process that output to substitute the values in and to get the proper column names, and even then I'd need a distinction between lines that I actually change the db (maybe I could just extract the inserts and updates). I also looked into these
[grails database migration scripts](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/2.0.x/index.html#ref-diff-scripts), but they appear to either look at domain classes (which isn't where my changes are happening) or at the entire database (which would sweep up a lot of user data too).

Thanks!